# replace each selected value with random letter/number

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm wondering how can I for example go over each specific text or number I've set and change them. For example I have:

0000-0000

and I want to replace each 0 with some input I've set. For Example:

1111-1111

I'm trying create random serial code kind of script so I'd just like to start of by how to do that.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** So this is how I would generate the random number or letter, just gotta go trough each zeros to replace them with random value:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    function randomAlphaNumber() {
        var values = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

        rN = values.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length));

        return rN;
    }

    $(".combination").html(randomAlphaNumber());

});
```

Comment: Could you show us what you tried? Might be easier to understand alongside a code example.

Comment: I think you should remove jquery .each() from the question name because .each() is for iterating over jQuery objects.  Here you are dealing with the chars of a string.  I would be looking at charAt() instead (See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt).

Comment: '0000-0000'.replace('0', '1');

Comment: [This](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/WtuMw/) is a little modified (without loop), now what ?

Comment: Now I have <span class="combination">0000-0000</span> and I'd like to replace each 0 with the randomly generated number/letter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At its simplest I'd suggest:

```
function randomiseString(str){
    var chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    var _str = str.replace(/[^-]/g,function(a){
        return chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)];
    });
    return _str;
}

$('.combination').text(function(i,t){
    return randomiseString(t);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/tnPTu/).

If you also want to use upper, and lower, case letters:

```
function randomised(len) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * len);
}

function randomiseString(str){
    var chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    var _str = str.replace(/[^-]/g,function(a){
        return chars[randomised(chars.length)][randomised(2) == 0 ? 'toUpperCase' : 'toLowerCase']();
    });
    return _str;
}

$('.combination').text(function(i,t){
    return randomiseString(t);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/tnPTu/2/).

Comment: That's perfect, cheers. However I'm wondering why have you used _str instead of just str?